# How to get a user component to be a data source for data binding in WinForms?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, components

I have created a component to fetch data from a web service. The web service returns an ADO.NET dataset.

I would like this component to be a data source for binding with other controls. The data to source would be the dataset.

So, I added a property DataSet to the component.

```
private DataSet _dataSet;
public DataSet DataSet
{
    get { return _dataSet; }
    set
    {
        if (_dataSet == value)
            return;
        _dataSet = value;
        OnPropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs ("DataSet"));
    }
}
```

I implemented IListSource for the component.

```
public partial class MyComponent : Component, INotifyPropertyChanged, IListSource
{
    ...

    IList IListSource.GetList()
    {
        return DataSet == null ? null : ((IListSource)DataSet).GetList();
    }

    bool IListSource.ContainsListCollection
    {
        get { return DataSet != null && ((IListSource)DataSet).ContainsListCollection; }
    }

    ...
}
```

In the method where the data is received from the web service I do the following:

```
...

DataSet = response.DataSet;    // Copy dataset from web service to the component.

...
```

I then created a new WinForms project with a form. On this form, I added my component and a DataGridView. Setup the binding between them.

Upon running the application, the web service is called and the dataset is received. However, the UI does not show the data.

I even tried to create a dataset in the component's constructor and instead of replacing the dataset in the DataSet property I merely do

```
_dataSet.Reset ();
_dataSet.Merge (value);
```

Still no effect.

Is there an event or method I need to call to have the dataset communicates it was updated?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you see the "Add Project Data Source" option? As long as your component is public and has public get/set properties, you can add it as a project data source, and then assign it to your bindingsource. When you do this in the designer you're assigning it as a Type. Can can assign an instance at runtime. I've never tried this with a Component though.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that option but I was looking for a more "integrated" way to have the component be directly a data source for binding.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any way to do this except adding a project datasource or by wiring it up at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is an event you need!  The DataGridView responds by automatically updating its contents against the ListChanged event of the underlying DataSource (which you can raise by implementing [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.listchanged.aspx)).  IList does not support this event, and without it the DataGridView will not show the newly populated data ***unless you reassign the DataSource property of the DataGridView to your underyling component each time it changes which you don't want to do if you will have changes often (it's expensive)***.

I had to learn this painful lesson myself here:
[Updating DGV IList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5421806/590783)

Let me know if I'm way off-base here, but this feels like where your problem could be.

**EDIT**: An example of how this might work -

```
  private DataSet _dataSet;
  public DataSet DataSet
  {
     get { return _dataSet; }
     set
     {
        if (_dataSet == value)
           return;
        _dataSet = value;
        ListChanged(this, new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, 0));
     }
  }

  public event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged;
```

Comment: Hmm, ok I think I see where you're going with this. However, my component has no knowledge of the DataGridView (and I don't want it to) hence I cannot reassign the DataSource property.

Comment: @Stécy Your component will not need to have knowledge of the DGV.  The DGV will have knowledge of your component (because you set the DataSource property of your DGV to be your component).  I'm not suggesting that you **do** reassign the DataSource each time - I'm saying that if you implement IBindingList, the DGV will automatically hook up to the ListChanged event.

Comment: I already tried implementing IBindingList before on my component and it resulted in the same outcome (nothing). Back then, I only delegated all the properties/methods of IBindingList to the DataSet. Maybe this was a wrong way. However, I'm not sure how to proceed next.

Comment: @Stécy Did you raise the ListChanged event inside your property accessor for DataSet?  This will cause your component to throw the ListChanged event, which the DataGridView should be listening for.  If you don't raise the event, the DGV won't know the data has changed!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to raise this event as the C# compiler wouldn't let me (complained about ListChanged can only be used with -= or += assignments).

Comment: My compiler does not get angry with the code sample above.  Let me know how that goes for you.

Comment: Ok, my error was that I was explicitly declaring the event on the IBindingList. Now compiles fine. However, I get an exception if I try to bind my component the a BindingSource component (Unable to cast DataSet to IBindingList). It may be related to how I implement IBindingList. For the record, by adding IBindingList to my component I need to also implement IEnumerable, ICollection and IList. I chose to delegate to the dataset by casting it to the corresponding interface before calling the required method.

Comment: Yes, you might have a problem with your implementation, if that is the case.  BTW - why are you using a DataSet for your source?  A dataset can have more than one table so it makes for a confusing implementation of IBindingList.  I won't have much time to help today, but I will soon.

Comment: Ok, fixed it by setting the AutoGenerateColumns property to true in my code for the DataGridView. Also, in the user code, I need to set the DataSource property of the BindingSource to the first table of the dataset (which is ok in my case).

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a "dataset" property to create a bindable datasource is not enough.

A fast way to obtain something like a bindable datasource is to use an already ready class.
You can create a class MyDataSource that inherit from the BindingSource class (System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource)

Then you can create an instance of MyDataSource, set MyDataSourceInstance.DataSource to your dataset, and then you can set DataGridView.Datasource = MyDataSourceInstance

Now: binding will work, and you'll be able to intercept, and eventually modify, everything that make the databinding works, you simply need to override the BindingSource method in your MyDataSource implementation.

(sorry for the short answer... I'm somewhat short on time :-)

Comment: Interesting, I will have to test this.

Comment: BindingSource is not overridable.

Comment: BindingSource it's a class, so it inheritable. Method and property are overridable, not a class. So, I think you should inherit from BindingSource, and then, in your inherited class, you can override the BindingSource method/propery, or add your own method/property. The DataSource property is not overridable, but you can hook to the DataSourceChanged event to intercept the datasource change.

Comment: Well the problem is that the BindingSource method is not overridable in MyDataSource implementation as you suggested in your answer.

Comment: which method are you trying to override?

Comment: The one (BindingSource) you referred to in your answer on the paragraph starting with --> Now: binding will work.... you simply need to **override** the **BindingSource** **method** in your MyDataSource implementation. ;)

Comment: opps... maybe  "BindingSource's methods" is better... :-) Thanks for pointing it out :-)